# nginx proxy cookie domain

Tags: php, nginx, cookies

I want to understand how to use nginx to proxy cookies. I picked up nginx in the docker, and set up two domains one e.dev and a second example.dev. I want to use proxy_cookie_domain, so that when the cookie is set, it changes the domain.
That's how I put in the example cookies, the file e/index.php

```
setcookie("Proxy1", 1, null, null, 'example.dev');
setcookie("Proxy2", 2, null, null, 'e.dev');
setcookie("Proxy3", 3, null, null);
```

But when I go to the browser or var_dump $ _COOKIE in example/index.com, then there are none, although I thought that proxy_cookie_domain would replace the cookie and proxy it.
Here is an example of configs in nginx:

```
server {
    server_name e.dev;
    root /var/www/e.dev;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }

    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 last;
    }

    location ~ ^/(index)\.php(/|$) {

        proxy_cookie_domain e.dev example.dev;
        proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;

        fastcgi_pass php-upstream;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME 
        $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
}
```

The other configuration is similar, only there are no lines with a proxy.

I can not understand how this should work?